# Looping through JSON array | Swift 5

Tags: swift

I need to perform an action on each instance of trialid in the following JSON array - How can I loop through each instance of trialid using forEach? The goal is to pass each instance of trialid to another function that only excepts one value of trialid at a time.

**The following is the structure of the JSON array:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "mobile",
    "orderid": 1,
    "trialid": 27
  },
  {
    "name": "mobile",
    "orderid": 1,
    "trialid": 33
  }
]
```

**The following is the what I am currently trying - how can foreach be performed here to loop through each object:**

```
var structure = [testStructure]()

func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "test.com")
        else { return }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "id=1".data(using: .utf8)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let nav  = try JSONDecoder().decode(structure, from: data)
                
                structure.forEach .. 
                    
                
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }


 struct testStructure: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let orderid: Int?
    let trialid: Int?
}
```

Comment: let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([testStructure].self, from: data)

Answer (score 0):

First of all please start names of classes, structures and other types with a capital letter.

If the API JSON response contains an array you need to decode it to the array type like this:

```
let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestStructure].self, from: data)
```

then you can iterate through your decoded array of structures (full code):

```
import UIKit

struct TestStructure: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let orderid: Int?
    let trialid: Int?
}

func fetch() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "test.com")
    else { return }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "id=1".data(using: .utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestStructure].self, from: data)
            
            nav.forEach { testStructure in
                // do whatever you want here
                
                if let trialid = testStructure.trialid {
                    processingTrialid(trialid)
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}

func processingTrialid(_ trialid: Int) {
    print("trialid: ", trialid)
}
```